# Git Extensions doesn't show up in VS 2010 after installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, git-extensions

I have tried installing Git Extensions numerous times and can't get it to show up in VS 2010.  There is simply no tool bar menu 'Git'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that since I had moved the 'My Documents' folder in Win 7 Git Extensions installed the add-in in a VS 2010 folder in the correct 'My Documents' but VS was still looking in the c:\users\'me'\my documents\VS folder.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be that Git Extensions installs the add-in for the current user only.

If you are having this issue when running VS 2010 as Administrator, and you installed Git Extensions under a different user login, you can copy the Git Extensions add-in files - C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins - to your C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010 directory and Visual Studio will find it.

Answer (score 2):

Set Git in: Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection

Comment: Might have to pick 'none', hit okay, then select it again.

Answer (score 0):

That seems similar to [bug 80](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/issues/80), which is still opened.

> Downloaded the source and built in some logging, but none of that logging was appearing at all on the non-functioning machine, worked fine on the local machine.
>   Which lead me to believe (correctly) that the addin was not being picked up at all.
>
> I am logging into a domain and have 2 user folders:

```
C:\Users\Sebastiaan
C:\Users\Sebastiaan.CAKAD
```

> The second folder didn't contain the Addins folder in Documents\Visual Studio 2010.